# Python script doesn't run background process, when called by cron

Tags: python, linux, cron

I have a python script, runned by cron:

> "*/5 * * * * python /home/alex/scripts/checker > /dev/null &";

It has several purposes, one of them is to check certain programs in ps list and run them if they are not there. The problem is that script when runned by cron not executed programs in backgroung correctly, all of them are in ps list look like:

> /usr/bin/python /home/alex/exec/runnable

So they look like python scripts. When I launch my python script manually it seems that it executes runnable in background corretcly, but with cron nothing works.

Here's the example of code:

```
def exec(file):
        file = os.path.abspath(file)
        os.system("chmod +x " + file)
        cmd = file
        #os.system(cmd)
        #subprocess.Popen([cmd])
        subprocess.call([cmd])
```

I tried different approaches but nothing seems to work right.

```
Some code update:
pids = get_pids(program)
if pids == None:
    exec(program)
    print 'Restarted'
```

Comment: Is "file" being passed with an absolute path or a relative path? Try it with an absolute path.

Comment: have you tried providing full path to python executable in cron command. like /usr/bin/python.

Comment: @0x01 in the code as u can see its abs path used

Comment: @AxeonThra, nothing really changes.

Comment: "file" is the parameter of the function, and it isn't shown how the function is being called.

Comment: That approach won't work even when it's *not* called by `cron`. It should be `subprocess.call(['chmod', '+x', '--', file])`, not `subprocess.call('chmod +x %s' % file)`. The latter is not only buggy, it's (like your `os.system()` code) insecure -- a malicious filename can make your script run arbitrary commands.

Comment: Anyhow, Python has a built-in `os.chmod()` function. Use it.

Comment: ...another problem that *will* be `cron`-only is the lack (on some systems) of a default `PATH`. Be sure you specify `PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin` or such at the top of your crontab (this can be on its own line to apply to all entries below it).

Comment: @AlexPetrov, if you don't set a `PATH` variable, not only does the script's invocation need to have an absolute path *to python*, but its invocation of `chmod` needs the absolute path *to chmod*. Thus, I believe you misunderstood what AxeonThra was telling you.

Comment: See [the `cron` tag info wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cron/info), which goes into some detail here.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I mentioned that everything works fine when launched manually, the problem is only when script runned by cron is trying to run program in background.

Comment: @AlexPetrov, yes, and the `PATH` is going to be set to a reasonable value when you run your program manually. It's only from `cron` that it's empty by default. Please stop trying to find reasons why the advice you're given doesn't apply, and instead *follow that advice*.

Comment: I'd also suggest `2>/path/to/logfile` or such to collect an actual error message.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy cron actually runs the python script, but the program that have been launched by script in background doesnt work and nahgs in process list looking like "/usr/bin/python /home/alex/exec/runnable". So the script runs well, but it doesn't start program in background correctly.

Comment: @AlexPetrov, yes, but the Python script inherits the PATH environment variable from crond, so when it tries to run `chmod` it can only find it if it's in the PATH that `cron` had. Stop arguing (if you knew everything about this topic already you wouldn't be here asking a question) and try following the advice that you're given.

Comment: (And change the `>/dev/null &` to `>/tmp/cron.log 2>&1 &` or such, so you actually get a logfile showing the exact error you can [edit] into the question).